# how to customize \pgfdeclareimage in my own style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, titles

eg: `\pgfdeclareimage[width=1.0\paperwidth]{header-logo}{ru_header}`

How to declare my own header in beamer, `\pgfdeclareimage` syntax and I have doubt what is `{header logo}` and `{ru_header}`.?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[<dimen>]{<name>}{<file name>}
```

With this the logo is available with the name `<name>`. Now you can place the logo using

```
\logo{\pgfuseimage{<name>}}
```

Where this logo is placed is decided by the theme being used. Here is an example:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.45cm]{logo}{example-image-a}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}
```

Here `example-image-a` is the image file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.45cm]{logo}{example-image-a}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Test
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, you can include the image directly using `\includegraphics` like:

```
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.45cm]{example-image-a}}
```

In your question `header-logo` is the name in which your logo is available for use and `ru_header` is the name of the image file.